# Call an Objective-C function non-virtually

Tags: objective-c

Is it possible to force Objective-C to call a specific instance of a virtual method, rather than going through the standard virtual message dispatch? I know this is generally a Bad Idea, but I'd like to know how to do it using the Objective-C runtime.

For example, given class A and B that implement -(void) foo, where B is a subclass of A, I'd like to call the foo method on A with the B instance (even though B would normally handle this message).

I know that I can make this happen by moving the guts of A's foo method to a new method and delegating to it, but I'd like to figure out some way to do this through the Objective-C runtime.

NOTE: For the purposes of this question, assume that I can't change the source of A or B and I've carefully weighed the risks of breaking encapsulation.

Comment: Why does `[super foo]` not fit your needs? Your description of what you want is exactly what the `super` keyword does. EDIT: Oh, unless, as bbum describes, you want to call `-[A foo]` from _outside_ of an instance of `B`.

Comment: Yeah, I want to call it generically - not necessarily from B. And I can't change the contents of A or B at this point.

Comment: The OP makes it sound like they have control over A (and therefore probably B), so I have a feeling `[super foo]` really is the best/simplest answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This page](http://cocoasamurai.blogspot.com/2010/01/understanding-objective-c-runtime.html) is a great source for understanding the runtime; a quick memory-assisted scan shows that the section titled "So what happens in objc_msgSend anyway?" is a good place to start for an immediate answer, but the article as a whole will really help you understand what goes on.

Here's an example where he queries the runtime for the appropriate function pointer, then calls the function directly:

```
//declare C function pointer
int (computeNum *)(id,SEL,int);

//methodForSelector is COCOA & not ObjC Runtime
//gets the same function pointer objc_msgSend gets
computeNum = (int (*)(id,SEL,int))[target methodForSelector:@selector(doComputeWithNum:)];

//execute the C function pointer returned by the runtime
computeNum(obj,@selector(doComputeWithNum:),aNum);
```

Comment: This is almost what I need. Given an instance of B, can I have it return me the method from A matching the selector somehow? Or can I ask A for a method matching a selector without an instance?

Comment: instanceMethodForSelector _might_ be what I'm looking for.

Comment: `[[target superclass] instanceMethodForSelector:]` (found in the NSObject documentation) would do the trick; you need this instead of `-methodForSelector:` because `[target superclass`] returns a `Class`, to which `-methodForSelector:` will not respond.

Answer (score 3):

What Matthias said... however:

> For example, given class A and B that implement -(void) foo, where B
>   is a subclass of A, I'd like to call the foo method on A with the B
>   instance (even though B would normally handle this message).

In other words, you have an implementation of `foo` on B that you want to avoid by calling `a`'s implementation directly?

Obviously, if you are the implementer of B, then this is trivial;  just implement the appropriate logic to determine when it is needed and call `[super foo];`.

If you are not the implementer of B, then this is beyond a bad idea.  It is pretty much guaranteed to lead to mystery crashers and/or misbehavior.  Worse, if B is actually a part of a system framework or something that may be updated via a mechanism other than your app being updated, then you have a ticking time bomb that may start crashing your app at any time on any random configuration of the OS.

Specifically:

- B's `foo` may not be self contained;  it may do stuff before/after calling A's `foo` that sets up internal state that may later be required for continued correct operation.  You are breaking encapsulation with a sledgehammer.
- calling the implementation directly is going to bypass any KVO in play.   Unless you happen to grab a derived method implementation, at which point, your behavior is going to explode when that derived method should no longer be in play.

Comment: I understand the reasons for this being bad, but this is more of a hypothetical question to understand the runtime better.

Comment: Yup;  just making sure the record shows that this is a really bad idea. :)